# Stack around variable "random" was corrupted

Tags: c++

I know this type of question has been asked before , however I did not see anything that helped with this issue.  I am recieving the Stack around variable 'random' was corrupted error every time I compile.  I am not sure what may be causing it.  I am just attempting to output random numbers between -100 and 100.

Thank you .

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

int high = 200;
int low = 100;
const int arraySize = 100;
int random[arraySize];


for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize; i++){
    random[arraySize] = rand() % high - low + 1;
    cout << random[arraySize] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Every time you compile or every time you run the application?  Corruption shouldn't happen in the compliation phase.  Also, I immediately see you use an index out of bounds because you use "i<= arraySize" when it should be "i < arraySize".

Comment: A hint: if arraySize == 1 (one element), your loop will access random[0] and random[1] (two elements).

Comment: I think you also want `random[i]` instead of `random[arraySize]` in the loop. And the expression for generating the random number should be `rand() % (high - low  + 1) + low`. Did you double-check your code for details like this?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, **complete** and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: mooiamaduck , you are right, I originally had it like that, but because I did not see my error , I thought maybe the issue was with that line so i started tinkering.  I appreciate your comment tho, thanks ( I ended up changing to back to that for rand().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing `random[arraySize]`, equivalent with `random[100]`, which is not allocated. Array size is `100`, so valid indexes are from `0` to `99`.

Also, probably you want to use `random[i]` inside the loop, and then use

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    random[i] = rand() % high - low + 1;
    cout << random[i] << endl;
}
```

to cover all the elements.

Comment: Yup, that did it right there.  I appreciate the help people!

Answer (score 2):

The access `random[arraySize]` is out of bounds. Valid bounds for `random` are the from `0` (inclusive) to `array Size` (exclusive).

Answer (score 1):

You are using indices incorrectly. Write instead

srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

```
int high = 200;
int low = 100;
const int arraySize = 100;
int random[arraySize];


for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    random[i] = rand() % high - low + 1;
    cout << random[i] << endl;
}
```